# iOS - Basic MKAnnotation Doesn't Show When Added Dynamically

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I am making a simple map app - I am sending and receiving locations and text on a pubnub channel. When a chat message comes in, I want to use a simple MKAnnotation to draw the chat (I'm aware this is a horrifying act of UX and I don't care).

When my app delegate receives a message on the pubnub channel, it calls a method in the main view controller to draw the text message on the map. The method should use the latest user location for the pin's coordinates.

I'm not sure why, but I can't get the annotation to show from within my method. I have tried building the annotation from within the method and showing it. I've also tried making a custom annotation class and calling it from within my method. When I use the very same annotation code but hardcode it in my viewDidLoad then it shows up just fine. Any insight would be most appreciated.

My App Delegate:

```
#import "MyLocationAppDelegate.h"
#import "MyLocationViewController.h"

@implementation MyLocationAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [PubNub setDelegate: self];

    return YES;
}

- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessage *)message
{
    NSString* text = message.message; 

    //Call drawChat method of MyLocationViewController

    MyLocationViewController *MyLocViewController = [[MyLocationViewController alloc] init];
    [MyLocViewController drawChat:text];

   }
```

My View Controller:

```
#import "MyLocationViewController.h"
#import "MyLocationAppDelegate.h"
#import "MyLocationAnnotation.h"


CLLocation *userLocation;

@implementation MyLocationViewController {
     CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Delegate map view

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    [self SetUpChat];
    [self configurePubNub];

    //Instantiate location manager
    if (nil == locationManager) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"Application: viewDidLoad");

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    userLocation = [locations lastObject];

}

- (void)drawChat:(NSString *)message
{
    //Create new annotation object

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    MyLocationAnnotation *chat = [[MyLocationAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:location andTitle:message];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:chat];

}
```

And MyLocationAnnotation.m

```
#import "MyLocationAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyLocationAnnotation

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord andTitle:(NSString *)ttl {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _coordinate = coord;
        _title = ttl;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Did your didUpdateLocation is getting called before  you are calling drawChat method. First check userLocation have anything or not.

Comment: Thanks Bhumeshwer - I have checked userLocation from within the drawChat method and it is correctly populated with latitude and longitude.

Comment: In didReceiveMessage, you are creating a new instance of MyLocationViewController and that instance is never presented (displayed).  Where is the original MyLocationViewController created and presented?

Comment: Ahh - that makes sense - thanks for the input. 

I thought this was a way to give the appDelegate access to a method in  MyLocationViewController. 

Aside from the MyLocationViewController.m file, I don't explicitly create it anywhere else - there is just a MKMapView inside of MyLocationViewController.

Comment: Hooray - thanks for your nudge in the right direction Anna - I was able to fix this: Instead of redclaring my main view controller in the app delegate I did this instead: 

MyLocationViewController *mainController = (MyLocationViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    [mainController drawChat:text];

I was then able to call the method just fine with the data from app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Anna's pointing out what I was doing wrong I was able to fix this:

Instead of redclaring my main view controller in the app delegate I did this instead:

```
MyLocationViewController *mainController = (MyLocationViewController *) self.window.rootViewController; 
[mainController drawChat:text];
```

I was then able to call the method just fine with the data from app delegate.